# logstash output not showing the desired timestamp

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to get the desired time stamp format from logstash output. I can''t get that if I use this format in syslog

Please share your thoughts about convert to the other format that’s in the _source field like Yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ  format?

```
filter {
  grok {
        match => [ "logdate", "Yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ" ]
       overwrite => ["host", "message"]
  }

_source: {
message: "activity_log: {"created_at":1421114642210,"actor_ip":"192.168.1.1","note":"From system","user":"4561c9d7aaa9705a25f66d","user_id":null,"actor":"4561c9d7aaa9705a25f66d","actor_id":null,"org_id":null,"action":"user.failed_login","data":{"transaction_id":"d6768c473e366594","name":"user.failed_login","timing":{"start":1422127860691,"end":14288720480691,"duration":0.00257},"actor_locatio
```

I am using this code in syslog file

```
filter {
  if [message] =~ /^activity_log: / {
    grok {
      match => ["message", "^activity_log: %{GREEDYDATA:json_message}"]
    }
    json {
      source => "json_message"
      remove_field => "json_message"
    }
    date {
      match => ["created_at", "UNIX_MS"]
    }
    mutate {
      rename => ["[json][repo]", "repo"]
      remove_field => "json"
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

thanks

```
"message" => "<134>feb  1 20:06:12 {\"created_at\":1422765535789, pid=5450 tid=28643 version=b0b45ac proto=http  ip=192.168.1.1 duration_ms=0.165809 fs_sent=0 fs_recv=0 client_recv=386 client_sent=0 log_level=INFO msg=\"http op done: (401)\" code=401" }
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-02-01T20:06:12.726Z",
          "type" => "activity_log",
          "host" => "192.168.1.1"
```

Comment: Are you asking how to capture the `created_at` portion of the message?

Comment: hi,  I would like to get the created_at portion output as this format Yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ , currently I am getting the output like 1421114642210  , its not readable. (created_at out)  , thank you

Comment: Say what? The final message example is completely different from the first one (containing activity_log). What, exactly, do you need help with?

Comment: hi, my activity log date format displays the date in the elastic search page like 'created_at":1420787386651' , either  I want to convert this date to unix format (date -d @1420787386651) and this output displays in the elastic search page   or convert the 'created_at":1420787386651'  output to Unix style Date format , thanks

Comment: my actual activity_log has date as 1422765535743  this format.  hence , log stash output also shows this date format and elastic search page also displays the same created_at\":1422765535743, I've already added this in the syslog   , please let me know how to display the date as converted to normat date format  date {
      match => ["created_at", "UNIX_MS"]
    }

Comment: Sorry, I give up. I've given you a solution that works with the initial information in the question and I haven't been able to understand why that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern in your [grok filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok) doesn't make sense. You're using a Joda-Time pattern (normally used for the [date filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date)) and not a grok pattern.

It seems your `message` field contains a JSON object. That's good, because it makes it easy to parse. Extract the part that comes after "activity_log: " to a temporary `json_message` field,

```
grok {
  match => ["message", "^activity_log: %{GREEDYDATA:json_message}"]
}
```

and parse that field as JSON with the [json filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/json) (removing the temporary field if the operation was successful):

```
json {
  source => "json_message"
  remove_field => ["json_message"]
}
```

Now you should have the fields from the original message field at the top level of your message, including the `created_at` field with the timestamp you want to extract. That number is the number of milliseconds since the epoch so you can use the UNIX_MS pattern in a [date filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date) to extract it into `@timestamp`:

```
date {
  match => ["created_at", "UNIX_MS"]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed information, I've used the above match , however, it shows the output at elastic search in the message field  like {\"created_at\":1422765535733, I've copied my code used in syslog on original post

Comment: What do you mean by "at elastic search"? What you're seeing is probably completely normal but it depends on the context.

Comment: yes, actually I am looking for this output in elastic search. I've that code in syslog and running the logstash , it outputs to elastic search. the date format is not showing the desired output , rather it shows like this \"created_at\":1422765535733  , its making hard for us to figure out the exact date . thanks again

Comment: Please update your question and post verbatim output from the Logstash process. Ignore Elasticsearch for now.

Comment: Hi I am getting this output in the logstash output   posted in the original question

Comment: please let me know if any change i need to make to get the desired date foramt out put in the elastic search output , thanks again

Comment: hi , I am exactly looking for date output printed in the elastic search in the page , it prints this format in the elastic search page created_at\":1422765332733,  I am looking for Unix styled format display in the elastic search indexed output page, thank you

Comment: I asked a question in a comment to your question. Please answer it.